# ¿Como alinear elementos?

Tags: flutter

Estoy tratando de replicar un diseño que observe de otra app a modo de practica, para lo cual no logro alinear los elementos de forma correcta, tal como lo visualizo en la siguiente imagen.

### Diseño que intento realizar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Lo que e intentado

He intentado de varias maneras pero no logro posicionar correctamente los elementos, si logro acomodar lo marcado de verde, pero lo marcado de blanco y azul no logro posicionar correctamente.
El código que tengo actualmente.

```
Card(
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      Row(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.ac_unit,
              size: 45.0,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            'Billetera',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          Spacer(),
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert), onPressed: null)
        ],
      ),
      Row(
        children: [
          Text('Saldo actual'),
          Spacer(),
          Text('\$0.00'),
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es que son componentes separados, cada uno está en un `Row` distinto.

Quizás podrías posicionarlo con `Stack`, pero por ahora para resolver el issue, considera el padding y size de `Icons.ac_unit`.

Entonces solo agrégale a la izquierda un `SizedBox`, así :

```dart
              Row(
                  children: [
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 30.0 + 45.0,
                        ),
                        Text('Saldo actual'),
                        Spacer(),
                        Text('\$0.00'),
                      ],
                )
```

30 = padding izquierdo + derecho

45 = icon size

Comment: Estudiare el `Stack` para ver de que manera queda mejor y mas sencillo, Gracias por lo mientras.